# coalesce first non-null, varying null positions in hierarchical table sql

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table with varying depths of nulll values  :

| dim | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| v | c | b | a | NULL |
| x | a | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| y | b | a | NULL | NULL |
| z | d | c | b | a |

Does anyone know how I can write a select statement to reverse & collapse the cols by NULL values? Take the first rightmost value as the new leftmost value, achieving this transformation :

| dim | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| v | a | b | c | NULL |
| x | a | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| y | a | b | NULL | NULL |
| z | a | b | c | d |

Comment: And what if NULL is in the middle of not null values?

Comment: I don't have that case in my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate all columns with some delimiter, substituting NULLs with some constant like 'null', extract null part, reverse not null part,
concatenate again reversed not null with nulls, split to get an array, and now you can get arrays elements as columns, do not forget to check for nulls and reverse each element to get values longer than 1 character correctly:

```
with 
test_data as (
select 'v' as dim, 'c' as col1, 'b' as col2,    'a' as col3,    NULL as col4 union all
select 'x', 'a', NULL,  NULL ,  NULL  union all
select 'y', 'b', 'a',   NULL ,  NULL  union all
select 'z', 'd', 'c',   'b',    'a'
)


select dim,
       case when reversed_array[0] = 'null' then null else reverse(reversed_array[0]) end as col1,
       case when reversed_array[1] = 'null' then null else reverse(reversed_array[1]) end as col2,
       case when reversed_array[2] = 'null' then null else reverse(reversed_array[2]) end as col3,
       case when reversed_array[3] = 'null' then null else reverse(reversed_array[3]) end as col4     
from
(
select dim,
split(
concat(
--all before |null
reverse(regexp_replace(concat_ws('|',nvl(col1,'null'), nvl(col2,'null'), nvl(col3,'null'), nvl(col4,'null')),'(\\|null)*','')),
--NULLs
regexp_extract(concat_ws('|',nvl(col1,'null'), nvl(col2,'null'), nvl(col3,'null'), nvl(col4,'null')),'((\\|null)*)$',1)
)
,'\\|') as reversed_array
from test_data
) s
```

Result:

```
dim     col1    col2    col3    col4    
v       a       b       c       NULL
x       a       NULL    NULL    NULL
y       a       b       NULL    NULL
z       a       b       c       d
```

Answer (score 0):

See example

```
select *
  ,case when col1 is null then col1
        when col2 is null then col1
        when col3 is null then col2
        when col4 is null then col3
  else col4
  end col1
  ,case when col1 is null then col2
        when col2 is null then col2
        when col3 is null then col1
        when col4 is null then col2
  else col3
  end col2
  ,case when col1 is null then col3
        when col2 is null then col3
        when col3 is null then col3
        when col4 is null then col1
  else col2
  end col3
  ,case when col1 is null then col4
        when col2 is null then col4
        when col3 is null then col4
        when col4 is null then col4
  else col1
  end col4
from test
```

For test

| dim | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| v | c | b | a | null | a | b | c | null |
| x | a | null | null | null | a | null | null | null |
| y | b | a | null | null | a | b | null | null |
| z | d | c | b | a | a | b | c | d |
| u | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |